# How to handle inheritance if a subclass already extended with base class

Tags: java

I have code where i'm calling a implemented method within class i.e cmpreValue(int real, int virtual);

```
public class TestCompare extends TestBaseClass {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestCompare.class.getName());
    String virtual= null;
    String real= null;
    XLSParser objVal ;

    public void testSomeThing() {
        // Returns some string value
        real= objVal.getSomeStringValue();
        virtual= getExpectedValue();    
        cmpreValue(virtual, real);          
    }

    void cmpreValue(String virtual, String real)
    {
        if(real.equals(virtual))
        {
            logger.info(real);
        }
        else{
            logger.info(virtual);
        }
    }
```

Here, `cmpreValue(String virtual, String real)` is used once but I want to use this function in my other class as well. So I tried my making another class i.e

```
public class Helpervalidate{
    void cmpreValue(String virtual, String real)
    {
        if(real.equals(virtual))
        {
            // Not Visible objVal
            logger.info(**objVal**.something());
        }
        else{
            logger.info(virtual);
        }
    }
```

and creating an object of Helpervalidate class in my TestCompare class and calling function cmpreValue in  TestCompare  class but then i am getting error **objVal** is undefined in Helpervalidate class.

As my class TestCompare  already extends TestBaseClass so i cannot go for another extending of the class. 
So how can i make my function cmpreValue(String virtual, String real) reusable to other classes ?
Is there any way where i simple add funtion cmpreValue(String virtual, String real) and pass the values and it works fine ?

Comment: Can you add properties to the `Helpervalidate` class? Then I can help.

Comment: Why have you got `logger.info(real)` in one version of the method and `logger.info(objVal.something())` in another? What's the significance?

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya: Yes i can add...please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in all the params you need in your Helpervalidate.cmpreValue method. i.e. change the method signature to:

```
void cmpreValue(String virtual, String real, XLSParser objVal)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . I can pass only two parameters in the function i.e real and virtual only. It's something like code freeze for me, i can't made changes into the parameter.

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so what is it?

Answer (score 0):

How about using helper only for the comparison, and do all the logging inside your class ?

If you have method named "cmpreValue", it's not right to make it do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In general: to pass information to class you have to either

- Store reference to `objVal` inside class and provide that value in constructor/setter

  ```
  public class Helpervalidate{
      XLSParser objVal ;
      void cmpreValue(String virtual, String real){
          //do stuff    
      }
  }
  ```
- Inject it into method

  ```
  public class Helpervalidate{
      void cmpreValue(String virtual, String real, XLSParser objVal){
          //do stuff    
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property `objVal` in your helper. Generate getters and setters. Set the value from caller while instantiating the helper class.

```
HelperValidate validate 
= new HelperValidate();
validate.setObjVal();
```

And then use this in your method as this.objVal.

Hope this helps.